# JARs that Maven have downloaded to my local repository is included in classpath but not found?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, classpath

I have a number of dependencies on my project that Maven resolves correctly. The problem is that it doesn't seem to find the spring-context jar-file that Maven itself have downloaded and nicely put in my local .m2 repository. My code doesn't compile, and this is the error message I get:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/kilroy/workspace/blogping-dist/blogping/src/main/java/com/vrutberg/blogping/web/BlogPingService.java:[21,1] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Component
@Component
[ERROR] /Users/kilroy/workspace/blogping-dist/blogping/src/main/java/com/vrutberg/blogping/web/BlogPingService.java:[22,1] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Scope
@Scope("request")
```

From what I can tell the jar file it needs is included in the classpath (from debugging Maven with the -X switch):

```
[DEBUG]  /Users/kilroy/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

This is the correct location of the jar file. I reference the above mentioned classes (Component.class and Scope.cass) through these annotations in my code:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
@Path("/ping")
public class BlogPingService {

    @InjectParam
    private BlogPingList blogPingList;

    @Context
```

The @Component and @Scope annotations reside in the spring-context jar, and if I unpack it and search for Component.class and Scope.class I find them as expected:

```
pioneer:test kilroy$ find . -name Scope.class
./org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.class
pioneer:test kilroy$ find . -name Component.class
./org/springframework/stereotype/Component.class
```

So I have no idea what the problem is. It seems that the jar file is included correctly in the classpath and it contains the classes that I require. What could be the problem?

Link to my pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/nsLp5VeU

Comment: Are you trying to run a unit test?

Comment: I have unit tests, however it doesn't get that far. It fails on compiling the code before it reaches the unit tests. I'll attach the compilation errors in the original post.

Comment: would you care to put up your pom.xml?

Comment: Yes of course, here is a link. http://pastebin.com/nsLp5VeU

Comment: your pom.xml looks ok. check the maven settings.xml - especially the repository(s) you have defined.

Comment: I somehow don't think this has something to do with Maven anymore, because Eclipse can't find the classes needed either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks suspiciously as if you have forgotten to import the annotations.

Does your code even contain

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
```

(or appropriate wildcard imports)?

Comment: Okay, well this is embarassing. I think I just figured out what's wrong. I had a similar issue with the Jersey JARs. Eclipse couldn't find them in my local repo until I added them as a user library, and I think that's what's happening here. I left the imports out since Eclipse couldn't find them anyway, and of course the code doesn't compile if I leave the imports out. Duh. Thanks for the eye-opener! :)